# Retrieving output parameter value along with other return values from select statement having more than one return value

Tags: sql-server-2016

Hi i have an output parameter to a stored procedure and its value has to be returned from the two internal select statements. I have `@nTotalRecords` as my output parameter that value will come from the below select statement how should i retrieve the output parameter from the alias table `TBL` in this case i tried like this

```
create procedure [usp_GetMessagesbyReferenceID1]
(        
@nRowsPerPage               int,
@nPage                      int,
@nTotalRecords              int output 
) as
select  
    TBL.createdate,
    TBL.templateid,
    @nTotalRecords=TBL.TotalRecords
    from
     (
            select
                  message.createdate,
                  message.templateid,
                  count(1) over() as TotalRecords
            from
                  nts.Messages as [message]    
     )  as TBL
```

i am trying it this way to set the output parameter but it is not working it is throwing the following error `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data retrieval operations.`is there any possibility to achieve this. ? Or am i making any mistake syntactically , Please help me out.

**NOTE:**
The retrieving of output parameter from select statement works fine if it returns only one value(output parameter value), but my requirement is it should work properly when my select statement returns more than one value(including  output parameter).

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh added the tag accordingly

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz my requirement is to return both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a lot to conquer this, but atlast i have achieved this through this way, I have written one more select statement to get the totalrecords count. I'm not sure that whether the answer was perfect and efficient, but it just worked fine for me. Please let me know if there are any other ways.

```
create procedure [usp_GetMessagesbyReferenceID1]
(        
@nRowsPerPage               int,
@nPage                      int,
@nTotalRecords              int output 
) as
select  
   TBL.createdate,
   TBL.templateid
from
   (
      select
         message.createdate,
         message.templateid
      from
         nts.Messages as [message]    
   )  as TBL

 select 
    @nTotalRecords = count(1)
 from 
    nts.Messages as [message]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
    @CreatedDate=TBL.createdate,
    @nTotalRecords=TBL.TotalRecords
    from
     (
            select
                  message.createdate,
                  count(1) over() as TotalRecords
            from
                  nts.Messages as [message]

     )  as TBL
```

Your code should be like this. Removed the 1st column in the Select. This will work considering the inner query returns only one value for TotalRecords. If it returns more than one then the last value will get assigned to @nTotalRecords

Comment: I am retrieving more values and when assigned the last value, the mentioned error message is displayed. Am I missing somepoint in your response? Let me know.

Comment: @Meena, did you try my code? This shouldn't give any error. Let me know if you still getting any error.

Comment: my requirement is to return createdate and output parameter, but in your code you are returning only output parameter

Comment: In that case you need to add one more parameter as output parameter for CreatedDate. Have modified my answer to get CreatedDate as well.

Comment: i tried your code, it is retrieving only one record because we have declared Creadate variable so that variable will contain only one result,  but in my case it should retrieve a collection, do you have any other answer to retrieve a collection .

Comment: What's your requirement? You have declared TotalRecords as integer which will hold only single value. You need both CreatedDate and TotalRecords as collection of values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139220/discussion-between-meena-and-rajesh-bhat).

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion, below code will help you to get the TotalRecords (int with single value) and CreatedDate (string with comma separated date values).

```
create procedure [usp_GetMessagesbyReferenceID1]
(        
@nRowsPerPage               int,
@nPage                      int,
@nTotalRecords              int output,
@CreatedDate                 varchar(500) output 
) as

select @CreatedDate=
  STUFF (( SELECT ','+ CAST(T.dates as varchar(15))
           FROM nts.Messages T
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
 select @nTotalRecords=TBL.TotalRecords    
 from
     ( select dates, count(1) over() as TotalRecords
       from nts.Messages
     )  as TBL
```